# Firestore database multiple range query error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database on Firebase Cloud Firestore. I'm trying to query the database by 2 separate fields using range comparisons. In Firebase I created an Index for it. But for some reason, I'm getting this error...

> Error: Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >,
>   or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on
>   'Lat' and 'Lng'

Why can't I use range comparisons it on 2 fields? Is there any way around this?

Here is my js query code...

```
db.collection("MyCollection")
.where("Lat", ">", 30)
.where("Lat", "<", 40)
.where("Lng", ">", 70)
.where("Lng", "<", 80)
.get()...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The constraints imposed by Firestore are almost certainly related to performance issues on the backend.  Remember that Firestore is a NoSQL database that's optimized for id lookups, so you don't have all the flexibility of full SQL queries.

Comment: You may find a solution that uses [geohashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash).  Look at the linked info and also search for "geohash bounding box".

Comment: Bob Snyder - Geohashing seems promising. Could you maybe elaborate a little more? What did you have in mind exactly?